# Is there a way to wrap a Github README video link in a table cell?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I would like to wrap a video link like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13440061/129455220-23fa27a2-c8f0-4953-b291-b4893959d5d9.mp4) in a table cell in a README Markdown file. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can achieve that by using HTML tag `<video>`.

Example:

```
| Video 1  | Video 2 |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| <video src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13440061/129455220-23fa27a2-c8f0-4953-b291-b4893959d5d9.mp4">  | <video src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13440061/129455220-23fa27a2-c8f0-4953-b291-b4893959d5d9.mp4">|
```